# Looking for a good AIML api in java

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, alice, aiml

I'm looking for a good AIML(Artificial Intelligence Markup Language) in Java, that I could embedded in a much larger java application. It would be nice if I can use a database to store the aiml files.

So far I found

a) Program D: http://aitools.org/ 
b) Program W: http://programw.sourceforge.net/ 
c) Charliebot: sourceforge.net/projects/charliebot/

b) and c) are based on Program D.

I looked at program D documentation but I didn't find anything that couldn't fin a simple example of how to embedded this into an apllication, in case you can do this.

My application will have multiple bots, every bot with separate config files and aiml files.
I want to use a database because users can edit a certain node from aiml files and I think this is much easier and safe to implement.

If you know other apis please tell me, or if you know how to embedded a current one I would appreciate an example. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Program O](http://www.program-o.com/ns/) has a database backend.  It is written in php, but it can be used as a basis for converting to another language (In my case ColdFusion)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and bumped into **Program AB**, which is a java implementation of AIML 2.0 available [here](https://code.google.com/p/program-ab/). It has many forks on github which suggests it is alive.